# Spring AOP misses something

Tags: spring, spring-aop

I'm just playing with AspectJ (1.6) with Spring (2.5), but it seems not to work in the proper way.
I set up my "beans.xml" using:

```
<aop:aspectj-autoproxy/>
<bean id="testBean1" class="apackage.MyClass">
<bean id="aopBean1" class="apackage.AfterReturningExample"/>
```

with the correct namespaces set and some other beans with no importance.
I use a simple bean to test advices:

```
package apackage;

        @Aspect
        public class MyClass {

            public MyClass()
            {

            }
                public Boolean testAspectJ()
                {
                        System.out.println("returning from MyClass.testAspectJ()");
                        return false;
                }
        }
```

And this is the aop bean:

```
package apackage;    
@Aspect 
    public class AfterReturningExample {
        public AfterReturningExample(){}
        @AfterReturning("execution(* apackage.MyClass.*(..))")
        public void test() throws Exception{

            System.err.println("\n\n####  After Returning MyClass.testAspectJ()\n\n");
        }
    }
```

And finally this is the testing code (in a main method):

```
ApplicationContext ctx = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("apackage/beans.xml"); 
MyClass bean = (MyClass) ctx.getBean("testBean1"); 
bean.testAspectJ();
```

The output prints only:

```
returning from MyClass.testAspectJ()
```

The strange thing is that if I use for the pointcut:

```
"execution(public * *(..))"
```

the log shows the System.out.println of the AfterReturningExample class.
What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution found!
First of all, **MyClass** is not an Aspect so doesn't need an **@Aspect** annotation. 
Second thing, **MyClass** must be an implementation of a given Interface (said **MyClassInterface**), and in the test code, I better use `MyClassInterface bean = (MyClassInterface) ctx.getBean("testBean1");`. 
I could use a class proxy, rather than an interface, only if in the **beans.xml** I'd added `<aop:aspectj-autoproxy proxy-target-class="true"/>` and a CGLIB lib in the classpath.